# Proof of local maximum clarification

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I don't quite understand the proof of this theorem:

Let $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable. If $\mathbf x_0$ is a local extremum (maximum or minimum), then $Df(\mathbf x_0)=0$

Proof: Suppose that $f$ has a local maximum at $x_0$. Fix $\mathbf h \in \Bbb R^n$, and define $g(t):=f(\mathbf x_0+t\mathbf h)$. It is then the case that $g$ has a local maximum at $t=0$. This implies that $g'(0)=0$. But $g'(0)=Df(\mathbf x_0)\mathbf h$. Thus we have shown that $Df(\mathbf x_0)\mathbf h=0$ for any $\mathbf h$,and so $Df(\mathbf x_0)=0$

I don't understand the part where they deduce that $g'(0)=0$. Isn't that what we're trying to prove?

Comment: $g$ is a one-dimensional function ($n = 1$), this case is assumed to be known here.

Comment: Well, if $g'(0)$ was non zero, then a quick argument shows that you can find a $t$ arbitrarily close to $0$ such that $g(t)>g(0)$ (or $g(t) < g(0)$ as the case may be).